# Move unused files

Tags: linux, bash, file

Any idea how can I move files which are not used by any process leaving support for wildcards using bash script?

Basic concept is:

```
for file in $1..$n-1
  if ! fuser file
    mv file $n
```

where `$1..$n-1` are source files/directories and `$n` is target path.

**EDIT: Working script**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Move files which are not open by any process
dest=${@:$#}  # get last arg
for file in "${@:1:$#-1}"; do  # get all but last args
    fuser "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue
    mv "$file" "$dest"
done
```

Thanks for help guys!

**EDIT2**
There is a bug in this script, used files under some directory are not checked by fuser. Will check this later.

Comment: What specifically is considered the criteria for "unused" files?

Comment: Not open by any other process, it can be checked by using `fuser` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass the destination directory as the *first* argument instead. Then your pseudocode is almost there.

```
dest=$1
shift
for file; do    # shorthand for for file in "$@"; do
    fuser "$file" >/dev/null && continue
    mv "$file" "$dest"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for code! I have edited it and added support to pass more natural arguments along with redirection all output from fuser to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

`lsof` will give you, if any process is using files inside a directory, if it is not used then move it to other location.

```
for file in $1..$n-1;do
   var=`lsof +D $file`
   if [[ -z "$var" ]]; then
        mv $file $n
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in "$@"
do
  target="$x"
done
test -d "$target" ||exit       # last arg isn't a dir


for source in "$@"
do
  test "$source" = "$target" && continue
  if test -d "$source"
    then
      # source is a dir, check all files in it
      for f in "$source"/*
      do
        fuser "$f" || mv "$f" "$target"
      done
    else
      # source isn't a dir
      fuser "$source" ||mv "$source" "$target"
  fi
done
```